# Fluid child element same height with parent

Tags: css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kZhH/2/)

In the left box, I want the child elements to have the same `height` with the parent.

As you can see in the fiddle, the parent is the element having a border of green.

When right box height increases, the child elements of the left box does not have the `100%` height.

Note: I don't want to use some padding.

HTML:

```
<div class="search_navigation">
   <div class="keyword_category_wrapper"> 
    <div class="keyword_wrapper">
        <div class="keyword_icon_txt_wrapper">
             <div class="keyword_icon">icon1</div>
             div class="keyword_txt">Keywords</div>            
        </div>    
    </div>       
    <div class="keyword_category_space"></div>   
    <div class="category_wrapper">
        <div class="category_icon_txt_wrapper">
            <div class="category_icon">icon2</div>
            <div class="category_txt">Search by<br /> Category</div>            
        </div>    
    </div>  
    </div>     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{    
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.search_navigation{
    width: 100%;             
    height:10%;  
    position:relative;
    display:table;

}   

.keyword_category_wrapper{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;        
    text-align: center; 

}

.keyword_category_space{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 5%;
    position: relative;    
}

.keyword_wrapper, .category_wrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 47.5%;
    position: relative;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.keyword_icon_txt_wrapper, .category_icon_txt_wrapper{
    display: table;
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.keyword_icon{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%; 
    height:100%;
    background-color: #FB7F27;
}

.category_icon{ 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #FB7F27; 

}

.keyword_txt{
    font-size: 1em;    
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;  
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;  
    background-color: #F89551;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px; 
    height:100%;


}

.category_txt{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;    
    position: relative;
    width: 70%; 
    background-color: #F89551; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `height:100%;` to `.keyword_category_wrapper`

```
.keyword_category_wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%; /* added */
    text-align: center;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kZhH/3/)</kbd>

[Stretches with long phrases too!!](http://jsfiddle.net/7kZhH/4/)